# Raspberry Pi 2 FM Broadcast Harmful?

Tags: raspbian

Is broadcasting Radioform waves from a Raspberry Pi somewhat harmful to humans? I'm on 89.0 MHz and the antenna is a small length of wire inside my home.

Comment: **A reminder to the community:** downvotes really should come with a comment if there isn't one already.

Comment: Not physically harmful (unless irate neighbours assault you) but irresponsible, as it broadcasts interference.

Answer (score 1):

No. The energy output from the Pi is insufficient to cause you any harm.

Answer (score 1):

No. FM output by the RPi is not harmful to humans.

FM is [nonionizing radiation](https://www.fcc.gov/engineering-technology/electromagnetic-compatibility-division/radio-frequency-safety/faq/rf-safety#Q2) and studies [haven't found](https://www.fcc.gov/engineering-technology/electromagnetic-compatibility-division/radio-frequency-safety/faq/rf-safety#Q7) to find any harmful links between FM exposure and cancer, though that's a popular myth. The FCC's safe exposure limits are far, [far below](https://www.fcc.gov/engineering-technology/electromagnetic-compatibility-division/radio-frequency-safety/faq/rf-safety#Q9) anything you could possibly be working with.

Answer (score 1):

Not physically harmful.  But the multiple harmonics produced by a digital output connected to an antenna could interfere with many other radio bands (well outside the broadcast FM band).  If those RF emissions interfere with emergency services, etc., one could get in legal trouble (with the FCC in the U.S.)